# SQL query to calculate growth in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, select

I'm trying to create a query (Query2) that calculates the growth rate of entries in another query (Query1). Here's a picture of Query1.

[image: screenshot]

Query1 returns the sum for various categories for each reporting period. I would like Query2 to return the year-over-year growth rate for each category. So, for 2012/H1, the YOY growth rate for A would be 1.0127 (or 101.27%).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a view using the first query, and then do a query on the view.
Here's a brief doc on views: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_view.asp

Otherwise (but I am not sure) you can do something like that:

```
SELECT * FROM (ANOTHER_QUERY) [CONDITIONS]
```